# find index of string in webbrowser from htmlelement.innertext

Tags: c#, search, webbrowser-control, htmlelements

I want to find string location in web browser and then edit that later if user want, I can find number of string with this code

```
    public int SearchEle(HtmlElement ele, string txt)
    {
        int Find_Num = 0;
        int Location = 0;
        foreach (HtmlElement child in ele.Children)
        {
            Find_Num += SearchEle(child, txt);
        }
        string innertxt = ele.InnerText;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(innertxt) && innertxt.Contains(txt))
        {
            int Find_Num += Regex.Matches(innertxt, txt).Count;

        }
        return Find_Num;
    }
```

And for search string

```
int find_count = SearchEle(HTMLEditor.Document.Body, word));
```

But how can i find index of find string in **HTML in body of webbrowser** (`HTMLEditor.Document.Body.InnerHtml`)?

Answer (score 0):

var index = HTMLEditor.Document.Body.InnerHtml.indexOf('your string to find');

Comment: No,That is not good, if string available in the source of html (not text) your code not work !  for example string in html source `<p id="string" ....>something for txt</p>`

Comment: Are you not returning the body of the html document as a string?

Comment: returning `Body.InnerHtml` not returning `Body.InnerText`